# Send additional product data to Google Analytics with Ecommerce tracking

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Every GA Ecommerce transaction allows me to send just two variables, name and category, to describe each product. I want to send additional data to create more useful reports. For example, I have t-shirts, jeans, shoes... and I want to send the brand and size too.

```
_gaq.push(['_addItem',
  'N. 87987',         // transaction ID
  'TSATR5',         // SKU
  't-shirt',      // product name
  'men',          // category
  'Adidas',        // A custom category
  '25.99',        // price
  '1'             // quantity
]);
```

I know that the example above doesn't work because the _addItem() method does not accept extra parameters. I tought that custom variables could help me to solve this riddle but actually they couldn't.

Is there a way to send this extra data to Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields that you have are the fields that you have.  If you want to get more data into them, your best bet is to overload some of the optional, or required fields.  I personally overload the "SKU" field with whatever data I want.  It comes up nicely in the default reporting that way.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEcommerce?hl=en

Another strategy would be to track events that represent the data that you like.  Events can literally track any subjective thing that you want to know, if you fire them off at the correct time.  You'll have to dig a little differently for your reports, but you'll get the data that you need.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide?hl=en

Custom vars as you have mentioned like to attach themselves to every single call, so that gets murky pretty quickly if what they track are not related to the user or session.

Comment: I overload the product name, indeed, that's a greeat idea. Then I create custom reports filtering what I send in the overloaded _addItem() method. I thought there might be a more elegant solution for this. The idea with the events sounds good! I'll check it out. Thank you so much, @Mike_K.