# How to handle SKU & EAN product list performance tracking with Google Analytics Enhanced eCommerce?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, products

Actually my question is related to [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/93177/how-to-track-product-list-impressions-clicks-and-related-sales) I wrote. And I do not know if [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57891/send-additional-product-data-to-google-analytics-with-ecommerce-tracking) is a good way.

I have following setup:

- product viewed in category list with SKU
- product added to basket with EAN
- product bought with EAN

We really need to have information about the EAN (which includes size & color of our products) but in our category lists we just work with SKU, because EAN is not avaible at this point.

It is kinda wired to me that Google Analytics works in [product list tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-impression) and product [add to cart](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#add-remove-cart) with their so called `product.id`.

If you put your SKU in product list tracking and EAN in add to cart/checkout tracking. Then you will have a product list performance list that has an SKU field with 50% SKUs and 50% EANs while these SKUs have zero sales and the EANs have zero product list performance.

**How can I track my EAN with my product while I still use my SKU for the `product.id` field?**

Maybe with [custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#example-product) related to the product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a custom dimension with product as scope in your Google Analytics Account.

[image: create a custom dimension]

Then you have to apply it to your `ec:addProduct` code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _ga('ec:addProduct', {
        'id': '<product sku>',
        'name': '<productname>',
        'category': '<product category>',
        'brand': '<product brand>',
        'variant': '<product variant>',
        'price': '<product price>',
        'quantity': '<quantity>',
        'dimension2': '<product ean>',
    });
</script>
```

Do not forget to send a hit or event, otherwise GA will ignore your `ec:addProduct`.

This [documents](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#example-product) helped me.